# How to change a publish template html to use a function that's within $ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS token?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

Awhile ago I found a little bug when the html5 was added to the iOS home screen. With the web app open, during screen orientation changes, the canvas doesn't scale properly.

It's because Animate's **resizeCanvas** code fires too fast. So I added a **setTimeout** inside **resizeCanvas** to delay it slightly:

[image]

I've been editing my html files after every export. But it's time I make a custom publish template. I'm hitting a snag at trying to make the code work though.

In the default template html, the **resizeCanvas** function is within Animate's javascript **$ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS** token/variable:

[image]

In my custom publish template, I added a script after the **$ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS** token. It doesn't work:

```
// Added below $ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS in the template html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', delayedResizeCanvas);
    function delayedResizeCanvas() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resizeCanvas();
        }, 100);
    }
</script>
```

The only way the code seems to work, is when I add **setTimeout** inside the **resizeCanvas**. I can only do that *after* I export.

I tried to look in Animate's folders where the template javascript tokens/variables are kept. I thought I'd copy a duplicate and renamed it to **$ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS_2** so that I don't mess up the default one. Can't find them though.

Is there a way to make the **setTimeout** code work outside of **resizeCanvas**?
Or to edit the javascript **$ANIMATE_CC_SCRIPTS** token/variable?

---

**Update:** Thanks to Muhammed Maruf, adding a setTimeout to the AdobeAn.makeResponsive function works. I can just add this script to my custom publish template, and won't need to edit any exported html files.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', delayedResizeCanvas);
    function delayedResizeCanvas() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            AdobeAn.makeResponsive(true,'both',true,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]);
        }, 100);
    }
</script>
```

---

**Update 2:** It seems that this method only works for a single frame. For movie projects where the timeline plays across multiple frames, it fires once or twice, then the canvas won't rescale anymore.

Adding a **setTimeout** within **resizeCanvas** makes the canvas scale consistently, but I'll just have to edit the html file manually after every export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems almost impossible to do, but I found something else to solve your problem. In the .html page there is a function called "AdobeAn.makeResponsive". You can call it in a frame you need in the program as it is called there.
For example, when it came to the 5th frame, I called it like this;

```
AdobeAn.makeResponsive(false,'both',false,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]);
```